# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling startNavigationWithSettings(navSettings)

Tags: swift, navigation, skmaps

I setup an example using Skobbler's Handling navigation events snippet. When I call

```
SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().startNavigationWithSettings(navSettings)
```

I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.
Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mapView = SKMapView(frame: CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)))
        mapView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)

        SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().routingDelegate = self
        SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().navigationDelegate = self
        SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().mapView = mapView

        var route = SKRouteSettings()
        route.startCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9667, 23.7167)
        route.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.9677, 23.7567)
        route.shouldBeRendered = true
        route.numberOfRoutes = 1
        SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().calculateRoute(route)
}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func routingService(routingService: SKRoutingService!, didFinishRouteCalculationWithInfo routeInformation: SKRouteInformation!) {

        routingService.zoomToRouteWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero)

        var navSettings = SKNavigationSettings()
        navSettings.navigationType = SKNavigationType.Simulation
        navSettings.distanceFormat = SKDistanceFormat.Metric
        SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().mapView.settings.displayMode = SKMapDisplayMode.Mode3D
        SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().startNavigationWithSettings(navSettings)
    }
```

Comment: Is this with latest 2.4 SDK or the previous 2.3?

Comment: Devs are looking into it- we'll get back with an answer these days

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the audioAdvisorSettings property of the SKRoutingService is not configured.

```
    SKAdvisorSettings = SKAdvisorSettings() 
    settings.advisorVoice = "en_us"; 
    SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().advisorConfigurationSettings = settings
```

Comment: My understanding is that Audio Services is an additional option that user may not use at all and may not include SKAdvisorResources bundle in his resources. In such case why setup SKAdvisorSettings? in order to maximally simplify the situation I intentionally tried to setup the example as simple as possible.

Comment: That is correct - this should not be required - in the next update we will fix this behaviour, but for the time being you need to configure the audio advices (you don't need to use/add the audio advices file - just set the basic settings)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will change my code as you advice.